Klaro integration text change "Let me choose"
I have configured klaro cookie package in my Angular project with all the required configurations, but I want to change the text "Let me choose":

What kind of configuration I have to change to change the text?

We need to set the translation manually, the path for this is consentNotice.learnMore!
Klaro Github translations List
export const klaroConfig = {
  translations: {
    en: {
      googleAnalytics: {
        title: 'Google Analytics',
        description:
          'The analytics service ran by a most definitely non-evil company.',
      },
      purposes: {
        analytics: 'Analytics',
        styling: 'Styling',
      },
      consentNotice: {
        learnMore: 'let me choose it!'
      }
    },
  },
  ...

Stackblitz Demo

Can you please let me know how to add title before description? I tried consentNotice: {         title: 'Cookie Consent' } but not working

@PathikVejani We need to use the property showNoticeTitle to enable the title Stackblitz Demo

You are amazing, I am not sure how do you find all this! Thanks a ton!

@PathikVejani dig into the source code

Thank you for the help! I will look into that when I need anything!

Need help: I am trying to change the consentModal: description but somehow it is appending like this: We use cookies to improve your experience on our site. The information we collect through our website is governed by strict data collection practices using cookies, ensuring that your personal information remains secure. By clicking accept, you agree to this, as outlined in our {privacyPolicy}. with default To learn more, please read our Privacy Policy text, any settings that I have to do? I tried to dig into code but no luck!

@PathikVejani Could you create a new question, will check it!

@PathikVejani like this? stackblitz

in consentModal: {}, I want to add description, it is added but it also appends default privacy policy statement

Can you please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78523046/klaro-customize-the-icon-besides-service-option

Can you please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78537300/klaro-accept-and-modify-preferences-order-change

@PathikVejani Could you share a stackblitz with the issue replicated?

you can use this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-y9rrds?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fklaro-config.ts

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-y9rrds?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fklaro-config.ts - here you can see

@PathikVejani the stackblitz does not match the screenshot!

Actually I am not able to access that stackkbliz on this machine, I am trying to make it

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-c7tpgy?file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fglobal_styles.css check now, Accept should be first

hey in your stackblitz, on click of Change consent settings it shows only "Save" button, it should show all there buttons "Accept", "Accept Selected" & "Decline"

@PathikVejani if klaro supports only it can be done, will check

It will be helpful if you can! here is the website that does the same I guess https://www.wheelhousedmg.com/

Can you please help me on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78793067/integrate-third-party-api-in-angular

@PathikVejani Could you reraise the question with the script file on stackblitz will check it

https://www.trilliumhealth.pharmacy/modules/scriptpro/Scripts/ScriptPro.WebRefill.js

view-source:https://www.trilliumhealth.pharmacy/order-refills/order-refills-number-starts-with-2

let me check and will update ASAP

It says TypeError: window.$ is not a function

Let me replace with your jquery.js

any idea? I have added your jquey,js file too but still same issue

@PathikVejani actually the folder structure is important, notice how both scripts are in the same Scripts folder and I added that scripts path to assets array of angular.json, that is required, also if possible download the entire script folder of that 3rd part application

I did the same but no idea why it is not loading, let me try again

@PathikVejani did you also add toe scripts array?

Yes, "scripts": [               "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",               "src/scriptPro/scripts/jquery.js",               "src/scriptPro/scripts/scriptpro.js"             ]

@PathikVejani restart the server

Actually the element shows after using settimeout, it maybe an issue? I used settimeout to get the element in AfterViewinit()

@PathikVejani you can actually take a viewchild of that element and acccess nativelement, maybe try that, some timing issues might cause this, are you using ngIf around the element?

no ngif, just simple html div <div id="rxContainer"></div>

@PathikVejani Not sure then, try viewchild. else keep the setTimeout, require a astackblitz to check why

TypeError: this.rxContainer.nativeElement.WebRefill is not a function

@PathikVejani (window as any).$(this.rxContainer.nativeElement).WebRefill({

Hey, I did some changes in this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-a37e3f?file=src%2FScripts%2Fscriptpro.js so that CSS can be loaded. Can you please check CSS is not loading!
