Arrange row column parallel using CSS flex
What I am trying is, "Your Privacy", Description and buttons should be aligned in same line.
HTML:
<div class="cookie-notice">
    <div class="cn-body">
        <h2 id="title">Your Privacy</h2>
        <p id="id-cookie-notice"><span><span>We use cookies to improve your experience on our site.</span></span></p>
        <div class="cn-ok">
            <a href="#" class="cm-link cn-learn-more">Decline</a>
            <div class="cn-buttons"><button type="button" class="cm-btn cm-btn-danger cn-decline">Decline</button><button type="button" class="cm-btn cm-btn-success">Accept</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

CSS:
.cn-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
    gap: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 113px;
    boder: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}

.cm-btn-danger {
    display: none;
}

.cn-ok {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    gap: 10px;
    justify-content: end;
    margin-top: 20px
}

Here is the codeply: code
Expected output: 
NOTE: Can't change the HTML code as it is coming from the third party package

We can use justify-content: start to align the buttons!
I made the middle element position: absolute and aligned the element based on the parent, I made the CSS as max responsive as possible, do validate it once before implementation!


.cookie-notice {
  padding: 40px 113px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cn-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
  gap: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.cm-btn-danger {
  display: none;
}

#title {
  flex: 80%;
  display: flex;
}

#id-cookie-notice {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 32px;
  margin-right: 18%;
}

.cn-ok {
  flex: 20%: align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: start;
  margin-top: 20px
}
<div class="cookie-notice">
  <div class="cn-body">
    <h2 id="title">Your Privacy</h2>
    <p id="id-cookie-notice"><span><span>We use cookies to improve your experience on our site.</span></span>
    </p>
    <div class="cn-ok">
      <a href="#" class="cm-link cn-learn-more">Decline</a>
      <div class="cn-buttons"><button type="button" class="cm-btn cm-btn-danger cn-decline">Decline</button><button type="button" class="cm-btn cm-btn-success">Accept</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I've updated the "Expected Output"

FYI: Can't change the HTML code as it is coming from the third party package

Let me apply the changes!

In this case I would wrap the title and description into another element in order to split the layout into what you want on the left and what you want on the right side.
The justify-content: space-between would place your wrappers one on the left and one on the right.
For the right section you will need flex-direction: column to achieve that output.


.cn-body {
    display: flex;
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
    gap: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 113px;
    boder: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}

.cm-btn-danger {
    display: none;
}

.cn-ok {
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px
}
<div class="cookie-notice">
    <div class="cn-body">
        
        <div class="cn-content">
            <h2 id="title">Your Privacy</h2>
        <p id="id-cookie-notice"><span><span>We use cookies to improve your experience on our site.</span></span></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="cn-ok">
            <a href="#" class="cm-link cn-learn-more">Manage Preferences</a>
            <div class="cn-buttons"><button type="button" class="cm-btn cm-btn-danger cn-decline">Decline</button><button type="button" class="cm-btn cm-btn-success">Accept</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




I've updated the "Expected Output"

Yup just noticed you can't changed the layout. In this case that would be difficult without changing a bit the layout., unless you use absolute positions like the other answer suggested.
