klaro "Accept" and "Manage Preferences" order change
I have configured klaro cookie package in my Angular project with all the required configurations, but I want to change the order of "Accept" and "Modify choices" button:

"Accept" should be first, I don't want to use CSS property like order:0/1 or don't want to use flex-direction: column-reverse; Is there any configuration? I found that in this reference website the order is correct: reference-link
The purpose of ordering is to fulfill the accessibility criteria.
stackblitz
HTML structure:


UPDATE
I am providing this alternative answer, where we use an IIFE to run a setInterval every 500ms, then once the accept button becomes visible and the swap is done, the interval is cleared, this will eliminate the timing issue you are getting.
We then need to add the js file to angular.json
        ...
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/klaro/dist/klaro.js",
          "klaro-customize.js"
        ],
        ...

klaro-customize.js
(() => { // IIFE run on initialize
  // swap the elements
  const intervalRef = setInterval(() => {// run the function every 500 ms
    const accept = document?.querySelector('.cn-buttons');
    const managePreferences = document?.querySelector('.cm-link.cn-learn-more');
    if (accept?.parentNode && managePreferences?.parentNode?.firstChild) {
      accept.parentNode.insertBefore(
        accept,
        managePreferences.parentNode.firstChild
      );
      // once action done clear the interval
      clearInterval(intervalRef);
    }
  }, 500);
})();

Stackblitz Demo

There is no configuration to do this, but we can use plain javascript to swap the elements when the component loads. I get the two elements, then use insertBefore of javascript to swap the two elements!
  ...
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    ...
    // swap the elements
    const accept: any = document?.querySelector('.cn-buttons');
    const managePreferences: any = document?.querySelector(
      '.cm-link.cn-learn-more'
    );
    if (accept?.parentNode && managePreferences?.parentNode?.firstChild) {
      accept.parentNode.insertBefore(
        accept,
        managePreferences.parentNode.firstChild
      );
    }
  }
  ...

FULL CODE:
import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { klaroConfig } from './klaro-config';
// we can either import Klaro without styles...
import * as Klaro from 'klaro';
// and the manually load the styles (e.g. to bundle them manually)

// we set up Klaro with the config
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
    <br/>
    <a class="button is-success" (click)="show()"
      >Change consent settings</a
    >
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  klaro!: any;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    (<any>window).klaro = Klaro;
    (<any>window).klaroConfig = klaroConfig;
    Klaro.setup(klaroConfig);
    // swap the elements
    const accept: any = document?.querySelector('.cn-buttons');
    const managePreferences: any = document?.querySelector(
      '.cm-link.cn-learn-more'
    );
    if (accept?.parentNode && managePreferences?.parentNode?.firstChild) {
      accept.parentNode.insertBefore(
        accept,
        managePreferences.parentNode.firstChild
      );
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  show() {
    Klaro.show();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

accept variable is null always, I am not sure why

@PathikVejani please check the CSS for the button, the same class need to be added inside querySelector

see the html structure i've posted in question

@PathikVejani try moving the code to ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit

moving to ngAfterViewInit is not working

@PathikVejani try moving the code to show method, with a setTimeout on the provided code

already tried that but no luck!

@PathikVejani do you have SSR enabled? please replicate on the stackblitz!

I am not sure how to add it because this configuration will be global.

@PathikVejani try adding to app.component.ts

Adding 300ms timeout works but still I can see that order is changing when refreshing the page! not sure that is good or not!

@PathikVejani updated my answer, with no timing issue!

somehow it is not detecting "klaro-customize.js" though I've written the path in angular.json file

@PathikVejani check the path, it should be relative to the angular.json file!

Yes,  I am trying multiple ways to get that js

your updated code can't be done in app.component.ts file?

@PathikVejani Yes it can, since its pure JS, I did it like so, but you can also do this way! but please note that you do not need to (() => { })() part!
