klaro-config module not found
I am integrating klaro in Angular app but some how when I run the command npm run build it throws below error:

./src/app/app.component.ts:6:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error:
Can't resolve 'klaro-config' in
'C:\wamp64\www\cocomelon\vcc\web\themes\custom\vc\frontend\src\app'

app.component.ts:
import 'zone.js';
import { klaroConfig } from 'klaro-config';
// we can either import Klaro without styles...
import * as Klaro from 'klaro';
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public url: any;
  klaro!: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    (<any>window).klaro = Klaro;
    (<any>window).klaroConfig = klaroConfig;
    Klaro.setup(klaroConfig);
  }
}

web\themes\custom\vc\frontend\cookies-klaro.d.ts:
declare module 'klaro';
declare module 'klaro-config';

tsconfig.app.json:
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["googlemaps"]
  },
  "files": ["main.ts", "polyfills.ts"],
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "../cookies-klaro.d.ts"],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}

klaro-config.js:
export const klaroConfig = {
  testing: false,
  cookieExpiresAfterDays: 30,
  htmlTexts: true,
  default: true,
  acceptAll: true,
  hideDeclineAll: false,
  hideLearnMore: false,
  disablePoweredBy: true,
  showNoticeTitle: true,
  translations: {
    en: { // ... all required properties }
  }
}

I am not sure which configuration I am missing.

When running the build for klaro.
It's recommend adding klaro to the allowedCommonJsDependencies array of angular.json
      ...
      "options": {
        "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["klaro"],
        "assets": [],
        ...

Ensure the path to klaro-config.ts is correctly set. I think it should be
// notice the ./ which means its relative to the current file, the location needs to be correctly set.
// when we specify like `klaro-config` it looks like its a package
import { klaroConfig } from './klaro-config'; 

If the above idea does not work, move the config directly into the main.ts or whichever file you are calling it from,  file and start using it.
Stackblitz Demo

I’ll try it and update you soon.

Hey, is there any configuration that I can do manually line when click on "Accept" button I can code it that cookie has been accepted. Actually I want to create that square box manually in which there will be "Accept and Manager" buttons and on click of those button cookie will be accepted or something!

On click of some button just show that popup!

when I specify like this: import { klaroConfig } from './klaro-config';  it says Cannot find module './klaro-config' or its corresponding type declarations. also tried import { klaroConfig } from '../klaro-config'; with ../ the it says could not find a declaration file for module '../klaro-config'. 

@PathikVejani define it in the same place you are using it! no need to import then!

what to delete or add?

@PathikVejani Stackblitz

Ok, trying it!!

Still have an issue, not sure what requires

@PathikVejani COuld you replicate in stackblitz, have you removed the import? if there is no import how you will get the error, maybe restart the server

I have commented import: // import { klaroConfig } from '../klaro-config'; then added configuration data here (<any>window).klaroConfig = {} but then I get error here: Klaro.setup(klaroConfig); Error is: Error: src/app/app.component.ts:186:17 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'klaroConfig'.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Can you please help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78891099/third-party-api-post-method-angular-blocked-csp-error-in?
